# What is the 'slope' of a function that has x, instead of y as the subject, called?

Tags: slope

We are all familiar with y = mx + b, the slope-intercept form with y as the subject:

- m is the gradient - how much y changes by an increase in x of 1.
- b is the y-intercept - the value of y at x = 0.

Now, this equation can also be represented Standard from Ax + By = C, again making y the subject, $y=\frac{C}{B}\:-\:\frac{A}{B}x$ :

- $\frac{C}{B}$ is the y-intercept and $-\frac{A}{B}$ is the gradient.

Then, setting x as the subject in the standard form, $x=\frac{C}{A}\:-\:\frac{B}{A}y$ :

- $\frac{C}{A}$ is the x-intercept and $-\frac{B}{A}$ is the x slope (how much x changes by an increase in y of 1)

### My question is what is this "x slope" called, is there a name for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the reciprocal of the line's slope.

Comment: x-step over y-step, thanks